# JSP code translation problem

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I am having problem with my JSP conversion (Servlet to JSP).

this is my JSP code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:directive.page import="java.io.*" />
<jsp:directive.page import="javax.servlet.*" />
<jsp:directive.page import="javax.servlet.http.*" />
<jsp:directive.page import="Inventory.Item"/>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Display Data</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <jsp:useBean id="inventory" class="Inventory.AddData" />
    <%!public class DisplayData extends HttpServlet {

            public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

                response.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                Item item = (Item) request.getAttribute("invenItem");

                if (item != null) {
                    out.println("Stock ID  : " + item.getStockID() + "<br/>");
                    out.println("Name      : " + item.getItemName() + "<br/>");
                    out.println("Unit Price: " + item.getUnitPrice() + "<br/>");
                    out.println("On Stock  : " + item.getOnStock() + "<br/>");
                    out.println("</body>");
                    out.println("</html>");
                } else {
                    RequestDispatcher rd =
                            request.getRequestDispatcher("/SearchPage.html");
                    rd.include(request, response);
                    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/AddData.html");
                    rd.include(request, response);
                }
            }
        }%>
</body>
```

This code was taken from a Servlet which shows an Information of the Entry searched by a user.

When I run this JSP code it opens a new page on my web server but `Doesn't Display Anything Just a Blank Page`.

Supposedly this will show the Information of the entry searched by a user.  Please Help...

In the first Place... Am I doing JSP translation right?

Comment: This has been asked before by your classmate: http://stackoverflow.com/users/525965/newbie Just read the answers on his questions, or work together with him :) Your current question is basically already answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175970/jsp-importing-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Scriptlets Method in JSP

1. import the Object item by doing this.. package.*
2. No need to import the java packages.
3. On the body place this code instead.

   ```
        <% Item item = (Item) request.getAttribute("invenItem"); 
           if (item != null) { %>

              Stock ID  : <%= item.getStockID()  %><br>
              Name      : <%= item.getItemName() %><br>
              Unit Price: <%= item.getUnitPrice() %><br>
              On Stock  : <%= item.getOnStock() %><br>

        <%  } else {  %>
              <%@ include file ="DataForm.html" %><br>
              <%@ include file ="ItemEntry.html" %>
        <%  } %>
   ```

For the explanation, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175970/jsp-importing-a-file) as per Mr BalucC's suggestion.
Then try also creating JSP using javabeans and EL.

Note: There's already a javabeans in your code.. `<jsp:useBean id="inventory" class="Inventory.AddData" />` view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178399/jstl-not-being-read-properly-in-jsp) for the javabeans and EL code

Comment: Thanks newbie... you are the best ^_^